# How to use if...else statement inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, xml, loops, if-statement, foreach

Ok im using this `foreach` loop to parse `xml` to add result data into my database I need to set the `$win` value but it always return 3 when it shouldnt b..

```
$myinfo = simplexml_load_file('http://mysite/results.xml'); 

foreach ($myinfo->Event as $info): 

$cid=$info['EventID']; 
$a=$info->Match['AScoreNT'];
$b=$info->Match['BScoreNT'];

if($a > $b){ 
   $win =1;
} elseif($a < $b){ 
   $win =2;
} else{ 
   $win =3;
}

$sql = "
        INSERT IGNORE INTO `engine4_event_wins`
SET `win_result` = $win,
`comp_id` = $cid;

    ";


    mysql_query($sql);

endforeach; 


<MyFeed>
<Event Sport="AFL" Description="AFL - Finals - Week 1" EventID="651239"    FinalDate="2012-09-07T00:00:00">
<Match TeamA="Hawthorn" TeamB="Collingwood" AScoreNT="135" BScoreNT="97"/>
</Event>
<Event Sport="AFL" Description="AFL - Finals - Week 1" EventID="651240"  FinalDate="2012-09-08T00:00:00">
<Match TeamA="Adelaide Crows" TeamB="Sydney Swans" AScoreNT="42" BScoreNT="71"/>
</Event>

</MyFeed>
```

Comment: Are you sure its not a typo issue? You are missing a `;`. Also try to use explicit braces instead of your current way..

Comment: @Thrustmaster you're right, I fixed the missing `;`. I don't think it has anything to do with his question otherwise he wouldn't have gotten `3` printed all the time ;)

Comment: @xdazz Yes, I learned that today, and edited my comment :)

Comment: var_dump( $info->Match['AScoreNT'], $info->Match['BScoreNT']  ); Does that show the values you'd expect? Are you sure you're comparing ints, and not strings?

Comment: sprintf without placeholders? what's the point of that? Just stick with a simple double-quoted string for simple variable interpolation. sprintf's only useful if you're going to be formatting/type-coverting the inserted values.

Comment: it has no problem inserting the data the only issue is that always gives the else value for $win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` the values of `$a` and `$b` and see why it's always equals :)

Another thing you can do is:

```
foreach ($myinfo->Event as $info): 

$a=$info->Match['AScoreNT'];
$b=$info->Match['BScoreNT'];

if($a === $b){ 
   $win =3;
elseif($a > $b){ 
   $win =1;
} elseif($a < $b){ 
   $win =2;
} else{ 
   $win =4;
}

echo $win;

endforeach;
```

My guess is that it'll print `4`...

**Update:**
My suspicious was correct, you're comparing strings instead of ints, that's why you get the `equal` result  (both sides are not empty strings, hence, according to PHP - they are similar... I know, it's not intuitive, I recommend [**reading about it**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)!).

In order to fix it, change your code to:

```
if((int)$a > (int)$b){ 
   $win =1;
} elseif((int)$a < (int)$b){ 
   $win =2;
} else{ 
   $win =3;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the feed and `the full` code (which will show us how do you read the XML before iterating it).

Answer (score 0):

I just added str_replace before if statement and is working perfect now.. that remembers me the parsefloat in javascript.. very rare but solved the issue.. thanks guys

```
    $a = str_replace( ' ', '', $a ); 
    $b = str_replace( ' ', '', $b );
```